# Is one Maternal Nephew (Bhanja) equivalent to 100 Brahmins?

Tags: puranas, smriti, family

What is the status of one's maternal nephew (Bhanaja) in one's life ?

Is it true that one maternal nephew equivalent to 100 Brahmins ? In which scripture it is written ?

Is it true that one shouldn't let one's Bhanaja touch his feet ?

Comment: Not letting touch feet is a common tradition in uttar pradesh and Bihar atleast

Comment: What do you mean by 'maternal nephew'? A nephew, as far as my knowledge goes, is one's sibling's son.

Comment: Maternal newphew means - One's sister's son . Paternal nephew means one's brother's son. @AravindSuresh

Answer (score 5):

Here is a partial answer regarding the status of one's sister's son. Daughter's son, maternal uncle, maternal grandfather, sister's son etc. are among the few who are fit to be invited (and respected) during Pitru Shraddha. So without doubt a sister's son's status is high.

> मातामहं मातुलं च स्वस्रीयं श्वशुरं गुरुम् ।
> दौहित्रं विट्पतिं बन्धुं ऋत्विग् याज्यौ च भोजयेत् ॥ १४८ ॥
>
> mātāmahaṃ mātulaṃ ca **svasrīyaṃ** śvaśuraṃ gurum |
>    dauhitraṃ
> viṭpatiṃ bandhuṃ ṛtvig yājyau ca bhojayet || 148 ||
>
> One may feed the maternal grandfather, the maternal uncle, the
> **sister’s son**, father-in-law, the teacher, the daughter’s son, the
> son-in-law, a relative, the priest and him at whose sacrifices the
> performer officiates.—(148)
>
> [Manu Smriti 3.148](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199928.html)

Some similar verses from other scriptures are as follows (from the linked page):

> Gautama (15.19.20).—‘According to some people, one may feed even his
> own pupils and also sagotras beyond the third grade.’
>
> Āpastamba-Dharmasūtra (2.17.6).—‘This includes the pupils also.’
>
> Yājñavalkya (1.220).—‘Sister’s son, priest, son-in-law, sacrificer,
> father-in-law, maternal uncle, the Triṇāciketas, daughter’s son,
> disciple, marriage-relations, paternal and maternal relations (may be
> fed).’
>
> Viṣṇu (83.17.19).—‘The son-in-law, and the daughter’s son are fit
> recipients; specially the Yogins.’
>
> Prajāpati (73).—**‘Preceptor, son-in-law, daughter’s son, sister’s
> son,—these deserve to be offered the seat at the Śrāddha to the Pitṛs;**
> the qualified maternal uncles also deserve to be honoured.’